How to get a row of DataFrame such that the row is also a DataFrame?
Suppose I have:
raw_data = [
             [("name": "Bob"  ), ("age": 26)],
             [("name": "Alice"), ("age": 29)]
           ]

raw_data_df = spark.createDataFrame(raw_data)

What I wish to accomplish is to, say, extract the Alice row into its own (one-line) DataFrame. Is there any easy solution?

You just need a filter operation:
alice_df = raw_data_df.filter(raw_data_df.name == "Alice").limit(1)

